# How to pick indices that are not in my indices vector MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing

Consider `A` an `m` by `n` matrix. I want to split `A` column wise by randomly picking `NumOfRandomColumn` columns. 
I have used this code to generate a vector of random indexes and extract the firs section:

```
indexes=randsample(1:MatrixColumnNumber, NumOfRandomColumn);
firstSection=A(:,indexes);
```

How do I extract the second section, that is , the indexes not in 'indexes'?

This did not work:

```
secondSection=A(:,~indexes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
notselected = 1:MatrixColumnNumber;
notselected(indexes) = [];
secondSection = A(:,notselected);
```

It's basically a way to form the difference set between 1:N and your selected index set. This can also be done with `setdiff` but I remember `setdiff` as being slower than the above.